# Convert base64 string to byte array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, base64

I have a form on which the user uploads a picture to the page using `<input id = "fileLoader" type = "file" />`. Using the function on javascript, i convert this image to base64 and send it to the server. On the server, I need to translate base64 into an array of bytes. I have code that does this with a picture that has == or = at the end of the base64 sequence. But if the picture at the end of the sequence does not have these signs, then an error occurs.

View code:

```
$('#modalWindow').on('click', '#btnConfirm', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/_AddNewCar",
            data: $('form').serialize() + "&base64img=" + $('#autoPicture').attr('src'),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#autoPicture').attr('src', data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public String _AddNewCar(Car car, string base64img)
        {
            var base64arr = base64img.Split(',');
            byte[] picture = Convert.FromBase64String(base64arr[1]);
        }
```

How to make so that any base64 sequence is translated into an array of bytes?

An example of a base64 sequence that does not translate:

```
> data:image/jpeg;base64,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 jBd36Uu79Kvy2zKcdahKEdRV7GTi0VwtSKKPlpAYoEOoqVcVGBU8CK2zMVPhtmpZceeAgAcUilTtbhUyJATnyqLocVCafRo012AFogMUeKYg0xDj0FGBUYqRTSGmGq5HSjMdCHx404kz40i7QxT4UJWpGPiM0POT13oAArTctHnzFIDfpvQBEy7VUcYNX5AxQ7ZBqi 1NESB69aZqWfKnAzTJICuc0wSrXJnYAVGVx1osKK7DFB0qdthtUJBJqkIvBSDkZFWIrmSPxyKYL5GkU8xStPsrldFuOdJdnAopbNX3Qj61Q7sjpUiSSJ41LXwra 0KS0deoqAxkeBq/HcE 9kVLhJOuD8qNmuxaJ9GMRF 8xX5ZqXuM 46N FWmtUPukg1GLfu3BcFl8gcZo2sWlAray495cfGgdGRipyfhVhEVFDLIynyz0oGkkxucg lJOymkiMKxGQDj4UgKkRyoI86kXlPVQfWnYkViCPCkCfGrLFM 4B60yKp8vpRYqK TTjJq0Y0A2HX0phEgOzD50Wh6siXmpz51bEKFQQQDUckRPRganZF6srqwz0ouYDJFC0ZU74 tLfOBTEJzVN19qrbKR5fWq7KfOmiZEBGOlIUZWm5aZCHVyuR4Go3HrR8tCVoKIGUmh5anIoSKdktGSEdGFYUhIR1FErjB8PSsdzdRFjzGaIIh6ikHzRA7dKWwULuVPhil3JQ7b0 afnNPZhSEAw60Y6bjNR85pBzSARjGdgPnURiIqfn9KYuPKhSaBpMg7o04VhU Ty83KeXOM GaXgD0B6bU9xaIiHXcU MZI6VJgVIIJRH3vdv3f87l2pboNGQE5Wki58cfKjOKQA9KHIFEkgSPHtNvnpUk1ipAeKZTnqD4VXz45OaLLEdazbd2maLWuUQSxPGwBbIIzsdqIOQMHB IomUnxoDE3nVp2uSKrocnPQJj4VGVJOORT8DTmJhQMjDrmqFbBaNs/wAlUbxt17sj5UZU0uYinYqK5HmKEirBYn3gKA7DoPpTsVEJWm7lj0FGwFNlvAmhsEi3gjwp6Mo2NwRTAA9WArn2OhxEDRBtsFfnSGFbHsuPOrCmLGDEoPnzVLlQ1AjByNzT7edTfZ4w27HlPTB6VFyhSykMSOhBprImDxtDfSltRLEWOzDpnemdGRsMRv0OdjRsmTo0NtilgULDfrTqzKRiiwS k0coRSrAMhOcetWzeCeMxzAPvkb4xWMJz12x60ahWGeYZqWky02uC4lvC4OCUY9N8gUTPdWpCpNzR GOlUVyDsalDGNcgnJpOxpr0NKedi3Jgk52phyr93PxFSLcj2ecDCjbanW4iIwY1J8xkUbMKQcFxEAyyR5Rhg4FDN9mbmaMuh6heuPSo5COYlFIU9BUZYg9ARmhfQfwXKfM1JFB3pYCQLgZ3FRiQgkjb4UHMQ2cH5Gq2ZGqLUdhNIGPMgI6Bj1 Bqq8bqWVtivUZpxK4zyswHlQu5brkmmpSsbjEAxmmKmjWTlYHAOPA1PHcxMQssQC77jqKN2hKCfsplPMUJT0/CpGbBODt60Jk/pCq2YtERGNvSh7s1Lz uaFpGz1Ao2YaINHkJ2JJqpeavZWLct5cxB/5g9pvoK0i/1m vCeecpH07qI8i/xPzNYyPfIUbncgV5s/MX7Eepj8B9zZu1xxXaBiLS2nm9Wwg/jVCfim JBiihhXyI5zn4nH5Vr9tHzsMbg7dCN6susIR2csiKAwI3GD8uvpXLLysj4s64eJiiroy8XE qF1QSROxOAnc5Y/DG5r0Dh7ReJdVjTvtFltsjm72RlQY9VJ5h8xWZ7KOGrrR9IaTUIYor68mEipyDvYUwAqO3n4kDYZxuRXgXbR2gX/F3Ed5pllPNBw/YyNBHAjFROynDSyAe8SRsDsox45J6sSmuZM4c8scuIR4 nt15HoGkEjiDjLQbF196JJ1lkH9kHP4Vhp POyq2k/bcS6nf8q4KW1m4UnzBKD865aZACe6VRj0xUTAuFGdycda2tmKSOoH7Xeyq1OF0TiS68mMQwfrMPyok7cuzBDgcJ6yR5mCIn/wC6uZrwZuAig5GFGKrcjMcKuSdh8aOfolXw6zsu3DsrmPLJoep2o85bBCP8MhrceGON yriW4W206/01LljhYbqM2zMfId4ACfQE1xYunxA 2ZD8DQXdvFHbkqjFicDJzU2/TH Pw7V7SdO1rQIpbzh7g3RtY05Bl WSUXMY8SYh7w/qkn0rx2PtTSYgvwvo4B8UuLhf ete7Hu2/XuCp4NN1Mz6xoOyi1ZszQDzhY/8B2225c5r33XuBeEO1nRxxNwhcWkOoz5LXCJ7EsgG6Tp1Vxtk 8M59oYq4z14kEoX k8nbjmzuSB q5rVvO3vBIP7siHP94VZtNZnuWBtLq0kJOBHdRdw3plgxX8RWp8RcOX3D pvpusW0um3a 0E5QySL05kb7wPmD8QDtUcUYhA/aSDH3sgirek/bRknOD6T/0b5d69NYSxw6vYS20jjmX2tmHmudm RNW4NTs7sBre5iIxnBblI talp tXlnbm2YxXVi 7W0yd5E3ryHofVcH1orjTdM1qMfqm4TTrvqLO8kzbu3kkx3T4SZH9KsnHNj5j S/wDTeM8GXiX4P/qM3dcTaXC7p37zMhw3dRlhn tsKnstYsL1gkNyokP zk9hvoa85 y3 ki3sNbtbi3vY1ZpVdOU5BGD5MpzkMMjbrUrKOVyR1wxB61y/wA5NS5SOz n43Hhuz08 yfI RFBcXEVtEZbiaOGIffdgo/GvNTxHe2ASK3uWUsPZQ4YAb779KoXlxJqJFzPLJMxHvSHOPQDw ArV aqtLkxj/D5bU5cG8XnGOlwuEgM14xO3dryg/M/wrHTcaykHudPjUeBklJ/ID861JB3ftuFBxjfqOvSo2Zi2EPtMdvyrF VkfTo6o Fij2rM9ccXao5YB4Yd9u7iBx8zmqz8QaoHAa/n5vRsD6VjAilcg78ucnbfH/SnnB2YkMxGDt1P8Kzeab7bNVgxrqK/wCGTXiTWGljJvX5B1yi7/hvVyLi3UI1KSQQTsDgv3ZH4A1q/eEDoMqOvhVqODMaks2SATgkU1nyR5sl Pjl 1GUxGjYVVYYyMjrR yRgEquDkKMA1D7uwPtHc48KQHN8vCuejo4JAqo8kiEgk82D0Uelem9kHC9jqd0dVe/sLy5tCGjs7eZZjbMchZJADs2x5R4bnr00HROD7jjKeOzSYWtgsqtc3GMkKATyoPvMfoOprpLg3TNF4Y0aLTdCtobO0U5bfLyv4vI/VmPn4dAANq6/Hxpfmzi8vLxpFmTtrGVFCyzB368wj5P3msBxB2acJ8RTST6xw9p09zIeZ7iIGCVj5l4ypJ9TmtqaY8mWK7/AM05FVZLvk8a6GzgPJdV/Rv4Wui76dfazpzN0USpcIPkwDf4q06 /Rh1SGQPpnEtjOAcgXVpJCf8JcV0N sMeNUn4othNqMKd8JdPZRP3ilECHo4YA5Hy/dlWM5tvP0euObecTwNol06sHAjvCu4ORs6D861 67E 0OCN0/0beZCwcm3uYZdwCPB/X8q7FTVQyhopi8bAFWwRkfAgH8KkGpZ6lT8QDT2Yao4Wv8As9420/JuOFdfjA6utlIyj5qCKPg/9TaPr4n7RNC1W906NCFtwXg9vPVzgEjHgCN/pXdR1RIo2kkMcaICzOTyhR5k15rxpx5falHLZ6Q721kwKvMxJklHjjPuqfqfwpq5cCdR5Na0jj/sIu7WK0m4X020jkAVnk0xWaPPm OfbzGa0bW K9I7O 0pdX7ItQe90a4t1l1GyaYtbyNzkd2pbDZAwQdypbrgla3TQ yMa6Vm1ZYtPs23GIV75x/RXbHxP0Negw9i/Zw1nHby6AkpQfyz3EyzMfMurD FS6TKTbVm1PDw72ncGWM93B9o0 gW4t5fdlgLDqGHuupyDjbYg5G1eK652C8VRaix0bVdEvrHOIlvGkgkxj7wVWUn1GB6DpXtXCnDdlw7osWmaDcz2unQSSdxC7iYIC5JwXGcFuY9T1rNhL1XjYXNvJyE4DwlScjG5DEeXh4UKTXQ2k zl49ivaBbuBHZaUxH3k1IgfQoKuxdknHpUCax0dGH3zqO59DhK6dE12B 1tYZQOvdy7n4BgPzpGdB/K2l1H5lU5x/gJzWizS mbww HP1jwFxrDaJYatp2g6lpSnItrjUGzEfOJxHzRn qcHxBrGa32UasHd9NeFox7sNzOC4GOnOFAOPMgZrpETWUjhRdIrk45ZMA58sHBzUkliG 4jD0OKjJGGV3JcmmKc8KqD4OJOIOD9f0ySWfUtEvUUDHeJH3qYB29pMj1rGWwzAqBieT2T5/TrXcr6fGDkK0Z8x/EVhNX4N0nVx/r n2d2fBpIlLD 0N6xl4yfTOmPmNfqicdzKXYl uM eKrGM55l2OcH4eFdLa12MaJchmsRcWLnf9lIWXPwbNeccS9kWv6arS6e0WoRLk8o/Zufhk4/EVi8E4nRHyscvdHmNwUUALkqPxOKgeRmdi25PkMfPFWbu0ube6e3vYZYLhD7UUqFXHyP51CYeVCD7oznJ2BFZ1Rvd9A4VhygHkxv658aIs2waRhgYHtGilTMChS4JzjB38qa3RHjDSAFz13OM m9AGWX2sY90dNiMUmIPUtsMDrUaSpK InLN443x8aBmV5GSNy5HgB psVGaveNZ DeCEm01UOpXtw8cDsvMsYUDmcjoSMgAHbJycgYPlzcZcUy3f2qXibVY5yeYEXcgx8gcAenSth49El5p3DVtGFZ2muEUA7c5MX8RW5fqSw0fhZ7aLItpZLW7tbqWNBI13G3JdWUrdcsjiRR0YR eQO6D/FHmZF b/yZvsW7YL681SDQOLJkme5PLa3oAXnfwRwNsnoDsc7HOcj2q9mZSd64q1ixm0y9VCRBqCuWeJBy/Z5A55Mf3fCuuuFdUfifhXS9UgjLyXVuryKgzyvj2h9c1TM6LL3RGdz9aCSZGn70pGZVPsuVBYfA9albR7qQ78qnyNDJoN9sV5W2HjSGIXzHqx tSLfHzqnJpGoR7mFj8N6qvDdRHDxSD4rQAXEIvtUEFtbyxpa 9KXOMtnbYbkCrWiaZZaayykfaLkbiWQbKf6K Hx61jxO6n2sipUuyOtO30Kl2bdHqGTkk5q3BfjmX2vGtNS79TVmO7PgaQza7XUAlrGOboD ZrH8Qcf6FwvAk2v6pbWQccyI5JkceaooLEeoGK0bjLideGOD7zWJVEjQRqkMR6SStsgPp1J9Aa4 1XUr3WtUnv9UuJbq8uH5pJHOSxPh6DwAGwGwpoDtJP0juAll5De3zL/ADxYPy/nn8K3XhPtY4L4omSDSNespblzhYJGaGVj5BJApb zmuAIBbQlU1DTXRW2D5dWHqM7H6VcvtAVoe/02XvYiCQrdT8D 6gKPpae6lQq3KwOxVh GDWndpesf6E8H3uu6fo0t 9qULwW85gCoTgu2AfZXOT7J89hkjmLsB7aL3RdWteHuLLk3OlzsIoLu4PM9sxOArsdzHnbf3eo2BFdh8ltPEQ0MbI6lWRlBBB2KkfUGgDxLgPtv4j4q1g2NlwQbpeTnLxX O6AyfaJjC74wOnz61sMfbboCtjWdC4l0xcKxnl08vGVYEhg0ZJwQCengfKtf4o7FLiz1OXVOzvUIbGR1OdPu5JEhUnxjkjPMoHgpyB4EDYaHrvCfbA98TJw9HcWShUXu7i3nYhUCZy7ZwxyxGOrHGKu4k8nvukdqHAurMEtOKNMDk47u7k zPny5ZApz6YrcFjhuIlkiKSRsMqykEEfGuPeKtF7QNT4I0TRZ Br S8sZ5Xkc2UTRqrAYEfKckk83NzZ6LWvcM9kXHnEd8NMPD0uiwY5prq7EltCB4eyCec ij44G9Fr0wp 0dF9pOi8NXBni4g4h0i2jCs8MtxPHHdWj HLj UQ9OUgEeZrmWcQGWT7Jcpd26u0aTxgqsoBI5lDAEee9ep6f jFpmkWwveMeLIobZGUOsMQjXJIAXndsZJIAHLnJGKo9p3D3DGhWOnrwfDfIiN3c7yKVWbbPMA4BLbbkALjArHNFNbLs6vGyOL1fR5tylnLEnGxB8qIRcoAjBK/0aYpK9wx7xwcAcpGOU NGsbqPvE pIrlfB3rkv8A2VeQqzsw 6q4RM/AVHJHIIyWkjjiUb7hQKy4VT1Yk QWsTxDoj6vBEsczRd0S2GjLKc frWapvkcm0uEYK61K3Op6IsN8n r6gkneBOZI8kAtuN8YU49K3bUNJv24j4p06HWtNv4JR sma1X2L6VZFUOQ3sK3O5QAdSTg43rzDVOHdVtQ bV5oh/tbcc4 O24 lbFY8f29xw9 p IYJ7ea2sjawXNjFGkhYTJKhkBAyAU388 Fd LVKk7PLzbOVtUQdocmoF4m1IRXPciKzt7xESIhIQV7lkQAAruPPbqa2LhC6k1Ls8k0u31C90 602 ZkltJjG4RskdCMj2m2rROPuJrTiXii 1KysP1da3NzJdmAzGUmWQgyMW9WGQBsAcb7k64b 4juZZbSeaAv1MblSR64qn3wZr 57Rba5x9pYA07ju9dR0S8XvR/i5hWVtu1XtOsgO9Xh/VQux5oFVm/ulDXhcev6ugwt/cEerc351Yi4r1iM 1cCT0eNf4UvyKqJ0La9vuv2oA1ngMSY96SyuZFHyBDj8ay9p kXwnIwj1bR9e0 Q9fYjmUfip/CucYON9QQ5khgb qCp/Or8PHpcBbu1dk8QHDA/Iilb BrH6dP2faz2aarhTrsMDnwu7SWL8QpH41mrWbhHWT/AOVa9o9wx8IL6Mn6Eg1yUOIeG7v/ANXpsSk9S1sB KnNELbgy9B5GWAnxWdkx/fBo2 oNfjOubnhO4A57Ys69fdyPqKwlzZXlk472NuXOMiuc9M0RLYA8PcT6nZnqO4nB/4GWtmsdV7Q7Vkhg46aa3JAYX4Mns Pvq3h60WmKmg/0htUDcL8OachObh5b2RfRVCJ LPXlfCPd2MU2rtELiS0kQ9yyk80ecOfLod63z9IOdLq 0SaHkMX2OVAYzlciXJx/eFafw7qUdvw4ggnFtewXJfvZVBjKEbqR1OfKqQi7eWqtBbWpl72xe7eQyHfngI5lPocbeh FYzh24VbiayV2khYGWBm6n GRkH4VlkubaW5iu7C1X7LLKe7tnBWBiABIQnioyGx55rASS2sV1pUtisiCN2icSEZHtZ/eaGgTFxXYouLqIjOQGwMZB6NXafYRxTJxJ2a6Pd3Mhe6jj zzsTkl4zyZPqVCMf61cg6woewuoyw5eRsLud1Of3AfKvdf0QrwtwjqlszEiK LAeQaNP/AMVK6GzpBJt9qwGvcf8ADXD9w9vq2sQwzIQrokbymNj0D8ikKfQ4rVu2firU FOBZ7nQ7aeS/uH zJcpC8iWakZaVuXcHGy HMc FcXT6nOiSxfb5gjlneMXU6hyTk5DDck77 NNAdt/ OXZ8IGnHEhMCMEaRbG4KhjnAJ5MeBqvJ kB2cp/7hlb rYTn/kriW 1GWWIRW1xHFa yGSOUgSEAHmYE5JGcZPltVIMp6yL/wDJn86qhHVfad258G63pVvpthcalMWvra4af7GUSNYpVkPvEMSeXoB9K8v13i DiWSO30xLkWNooYyTLh3cjlHjsOUDxOfPz8r0 0udQvUtNPt5ru6kPKkUCGR2PoBXsFv2ftwrwqo1yXu KLydJPsCSBhbWwU/yvk5JBA6j61OWVY6NMCvIjV762kuzCwuXhmhJKODkHPUMvjSCy43Vc/0XGPlnes22mS7FSSPUUH6snGR1 JzXDsj06XZsyLaA4Jlwejc29EgtgzYBYEco5gW Y8j6/GseXK5Crgep3wKTS8zFtj036Z8fCoErL6C2GPYdd hJ/yaCZIZ8LMiOgP 0AY49M1UUsSD3igeTNnFSpIQNpGBxkco9aQCFjYxSExWkEbnqY4VB/KmmtYZU5HjR1B6PGrDHzFSc7ltyc4wTnOf87VOGd p6eH8aKC6MLccPaTPvJp1kQc792EP HGaxl3wVoUyoY4ZIDygHupWOT5 1n6DatyWN YMzLgenj8aIxIdsDGAB57CmpSXTJag 0ecy9nNtJvbXtwufB4lbH0IrH3HZtdrnuL23k9HjdD vVFVg/syIR5EDFIq65YMCSPPH0qlmmvZLxY36PGLngLWYTgQwy5/wB3MpP0ODWLueGNYtyRJp10MeIj5h Ga94ZnyRkjby6/wDWowpb3WQDGeoFWvIkuzN PB9HPMtrPbt 1jkjI/nqV/OrNvqup238hfXKgeAkJH06V740XOjZXmHQ8wyCPnWLm0XT7hj32n2jHxJhA tWvJvtEvxvjPGtR1zUNSto4b6UTLGzFSUGRzAA7j4D6VmuA9cls49R0YrE1vqyLCwlxgEH16Z6Zr0W 4c0u7TluLC2wPZVkXu2A9CuPCtX1Ts5Vw76ZcujfdjnGQf7Q3/CtIeRH3wZz8d uS1bJcC20yxuHWKaTULqFXABETNHiMLkbLkL9TWn6rNNdajZQXNoLa Rz36gYJOcDI8DgVkbwcW6ZaNb3EE0sBYOJBGJt1GA3MPEA NYjT9N1i5u5LkWF7cTyEkyNGep6ksfGtnOLVpmCxyTpoyOqXATT7gk45lIHqScf9a3r9HXj3S DxqsGr3It1nkjkjZgSDhXB/Na83v9H1ybCS6fchFOwROYE/EdagXhjWDgDS73fbeIioUo12W4yvo69l7fuF7Y/s721f1RXBP0qjd/pIcMsMSESjptAzfmK5Xj4R1pt/1fKo82ZRj8asw8Faq7LzrBGpI3MnN Qo3ivYLHN joGT9IPhO1kkkstCTvH95orGNS3xJxmsLrf6Q l6hCUk4Nsr5R7q3sERX6YNeRW/At0xHeXcCZ/mKz/wrP6VwnYWbKzg3Mwz7UvuqfML/AN6l5YrotYJPvg3PT 1HXbuwkGl6bp/C1rKcCPSrZYWdfMsACPlisQblpC7PlpGPMzMeYk ZzvnbqaQ09gAQpI8yucee9ELZVOGSTIO6qK5pTcnZ1xjGCpA9 MjIbJ3GNqJZ3xus2/kCaYxqJTzd4rDcbVIsKY3Z/nQO0ZbuHYjmK5z8Nqk7kZIwq IqRQQehHh7Qxt5/Cpo4JJA7IvPyDmbB6D4dTRRluyssWBuvKfCpBHzAg7 XpR759tuvTH76LJ5j7J tKkGzBWPlAICnbGcURLLjOAOvSkH9kjxHhiiLEDAUZo1QbMEZycbZJzvSZSTy5 VEWPQnceGKXMxGCMYGetFINmM3UZbPz/Oky5XGNzvv0owcDGc7Z NIAfzSc9TRQWwc55cxnB2yBt86JV5slkByOox1p2A 6o6daUaopwFCHyooLZGVQsQfe9R1PhQ8iEkMFAbYsd6s4XDOCvXGAcnp VCyjvAQcHIG4zS4C2QGLdjzA Pl/2pGMBjkOd nNzVY5UGNiBimJwBzZAG etAWVu7BAIJBHrSMAbflJPqelWOUAYB gpimTkswOflRSHbK7R xhuZcjG2xFCyRhs z0zkGrQjz0PXYbUwi/z0p0Kyv3fLuqYyMj4VH9lUnLFh4kHx9avNEh5SwHMpyCNsUxxsM5zvscUahsU 5VQCNuhx1yBQmNChHIQpGdvM1bKDP3SAaSxqB7W/jv8AnTSFZUCoGUAvtsPDPnmkQDgq3jsDVnkwMKcbZJzQEH3j1z4LVCsgdDyjcnxIU4 uah7rP 8/suR W1XHBCllGWHTOBUDvynHsj45pisyQh5ZpYyVIQKfdAyG8KiidJLoRPEhKg 1656jypUq5LZrXRce3jAU 0WwWO/kSKGaNYy7ADAXOMUqVNSdjcVVkwhUWzSsAQhG2MZBz4/KojEhRmCrjlyBjpk0qVGzFSEsK8xzjHMVHp/nFBOgQIMKSzlc4pUqpSYqQUkHsLytgnxKg7ZXp9aL7PvgORkdcdMGlSqrECYsMPaO fCm7hSV9c9fClSpoQlHMuBt1P0pih5iQ2D4bdKVKkxiAwAdsjxx60A3OPxpUqBgkkEYx9KZkICgtnP76VKnYhBjjqdt/wAadckjJPWlSp xDY6eR3piABkDptSpUAPjrv5UOfbYeWAM/ClSqvQhAZ32pjtSpUIQzpuRnw8RVdkBPRcdB7NKlQyl2f/Z
```

Error:

> length of string or Base-64 character array

Comment: Did you already tried to remove slashes and use Base64 converter to see the result? If the slashes could be safely removed to be converted as image, then you may look for previous post to remove them.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yea, i try used you option. First: `string processed = base64str.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');` and second `switch (base64str.Length % 4)
            {
                case 2:
                    processed += "==";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    processed += "=";
                    break;
            }` but result operation `base64str.Length % 4` for base64 line from my question 0, and my base64 line remains without signs = or == at the end of the line, and an error also takes off. I add an error to the question.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Added by.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto It is necessary either to fix it or to find another more correct way to transfer the image to the server.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Can you say something? How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can using the following code

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

you can find more at
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Base64-string-to-Byte-Array-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Have you ever seen what I wrote in the question? I already have an example of this code there.

Comment: i have seen if you split the base64 string it will get use less better you first convert base64string to byte array then split the chunks.

Comment: Immediately it will not convert. There you need to remove the header line `data:image/jpeg;base64,`.

Comment: `base64string.split(',')[1]` use this code in your javascript to remove this and send to action just base 64 string